# Create pairs with weighting

Tags: matlab

Programming has been a while for me, apologies.

I have a list of pairs, where the pair is a person and the affiliated group of the person. That is `X = {'Person1','GroupA';'Person2','GroupB';'Person3','GroupA';...}`

Now I would like to create random pairs of the people in this list. This is pretty straightforward. However, I would like that the probability of two person matching which are in the same group to be low, e.g., 10% or x% and people from different groups 90%.

Does someone have a algorithm for this? Preferably MATLAB or a different programming language?

Answer (score 0):

You can build the list picking the right around of percentage yourself then use function like randperm to shuffle them and make the list ramdom.